# Parsing an epub file and displaying its contents on a website?

Tags: epub, html

I want to show my epub files on my site, so I'm thinking of creating my own reader in PHP. First I need to know how to read this file type.

Can I show the HTML files that are in the epub directly in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the files are 'real' HTML (or rather XHTML) and will work in any web browser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I open an epub i can see the html files, these files are always there or they can be also in some subfolders?

Comment: Those files usually are in a directory calles OEBPS, but in theory, they could be anywhere (the file `META-INF/container.xml` points to them).

Comment: In the file you are mentioning i found this:  `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<container version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">
   <rootfiles>
      <rootfile full-path="content.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
   </rootfiles>
</container> ` it points only to the opf file.

Comment: So your `content.opf` is in the root directory?

Comment: Yes. But i need ti know where are the HTML files, I want to interpret them.

Comment: Read the [specification](http://idpf.org/epub).